# How to make images fit carousel containers?

Tags: css

I am trying to make all the images of different heights and widths within the carousel the same height matching the size of the carousel container '.carouselWrapper'

https://codepen.io/SashaSashaSasha/pen/MWgepEe

HTML

```
<div class="carouselWrapper">   
  <div class="carousel">
    <div><img src="https://trendland.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Myles_Pedlar_3.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://1aike31wshtt3k0e9u2nxtwz-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Myles_Pedlar_13-770x1090.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://trendland.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Myles_Pedlar_3.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://1aike31wshtt3k0e9u2nxtwz-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Myles_Pedlar_13-770x1090.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img { 
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  margin: auto; 
}

.carouselWrapper {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100
}


.carousel{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.slick-slide{
   margin: 10px;
}

.slick-slide img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this example. Hoping this is what you're looking for. All the best!

```css
.carousel-inner .item{ height:500px; background-size:cover;background-position: center center;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/1024x700)  ">
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/100x100)  ">
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/1024x700)  ">
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/200x200)  ">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

        <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your css.

```
.slick-list, .slick-track {
  height: 100%;
}

.slick-slide img{
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: This is warping the images!

Answer (score 0):

See if this what you want, I'm just inherit the img in "carousel div" and set the div with 100%

```
    .carousel{  max-height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
    .carousel div {  width:100%; height: 100%;  }

.carousel div img { 
    max-width:100% ;
  max-height:100%;
  width:auto;
    margin: auto; 
}

    .carouselWrapper {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 80vh;
        width: 100
    }


    .carousel{
      width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      margin:0px auto;
    }
```

this was the result
[image]

Comment: I dont want the images to be distorted I want all the images the same height but maintaining their retrospective widths

Comment: I make a update in the .carousel div img, pls check if was this that you want, the result was the image below

Comment: This works perfectly in terms of the image sizing, however the carousel is only displaying one image at a time where before it would show the parts of the next and previous image like in my codepen example